# HumaneJs notifications bound to DIV

Tags: javascript

I am using HumaneJs http://wavded.github.com/humane-js/ to display notifications. Everything is working well except that I cant seem to specify a DIV where my notifications should appear. The discussion in this link https://github.com/wavded/humane-js/pull/32 seems to indicate that it is possible but I am not able to get it to work

Here is my HTML code

```
<button id="1">Display default notification</button><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div id="container">
    <button id="2">Display notification inside div</button><br/><br/>
</div>
```

and here is the Javascript

```
/*display notification in default position*/
$("#1").click(function() {
  humane.log("Default notification");
});


/*display notification inside div*/
$("#2").click(function() {
    var custom = humane.create({container: $("#container")[0]});
    custom.log("Notification inside div");
});
```

I have also setup a fiddle to demonstrate the issue

http://jsfiddle.net/ZvCvJ/

Clicking on the button seems to display the notification in the default position(top-right) every time and I am not able to display the notification inside the DIV. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is displaying in the corner is because you are using the default `libnotify`

Add `baseCls: "humane-bigbox"` and it should fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/ThdLC/

Comment: Libnotify displays it in the corner but it should still be inside the containing DIV. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I will check it later.  I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS of the individual themes in Humane don't look like they take the 'container' into account.
Another notification plugin that explicitly supports this 'container restricted' notification is Noty.
http://needim.github.io/noty/#custom-container